# How to display a webpage in a html page from an url?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I want to display 2 webpages in single aspx webpage is it possible ?

for example

user -- open link for www.mywebsite.com

In my homepage i want to display both www.google.com and www.bing.com.

In the background i call two different url's and they should display on my same aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To integrate websites in other websites use an `iframe` like this:

```
 <iframe src="http://www.bing.com"></iframe>
```

More information: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)

**Google**
This will not work for google because of their therms and services:

> 1.3 Your Obligations. You shall receive a Query from the End User and shall forward that Query to Google. **You maynot in any way frame, cache or modify the Results** produced by Google, except as otherwise agreed to between You and Google.

So if you want to integrate Google search to your website, you can read more about the API **here** [Google Api](http://www.google.com/cse/)

**Bing**
To embend searchresults from bing take a look at [the Bing api](http://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search). 5000 queries per day are free.

Comment: will not work for google, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8700636/how-to-show-google-com-in-an-iframe

Comment: @Pepe Unfrotunanly no. But if you want to integrate Google search: check this SO Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028934/how-to-show-google-search-results-embedded-in-my-website

Comment: Thank you for your answer... :) I didn't find anything before regarding this.  My search terms are different i guess.